# How make text label same size as text size

Tags: flutter

I want to make label size same as the text size of textfield. when it is clicked the label is going up and size is decreased.

here are some code that i have tried

```
 child: TextField(

                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),

                      obscureText: true,
                      cursorColor: AppColors.gray,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Confirm Password",
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: AppColors.gray,
                             fontSize: 12

                          ),

                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppColors.gray)),
                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppColors.gray)),
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2)),
                    ))
```

Comment: You will have to manually implement this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can that do that. Perhaps what you want is another `Text()` above your `TextField()` inside a `Column()`.